# What could be reason for "Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4"?

Tags: java, linux, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to develop simple javafx programs in Oracle Linux using eclipse IDE.
i have installed jdk 7 and all programs runs properly except it shows

```
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
```

in console.

For example,Following is the simple javaFX program

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class practiceFX extends Application{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Group root =new Group();
    Scene scene =new Scene(root,200,300);
    primaryStage.setTitle("PRACTICE");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(true);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    System.out.println("hi");

}
}
```

and the output is

```
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4
hi
```

Please see the screenshot too
Also I can not run the javaFX samples.
When i am trying to run Ensemble.jar then it shows following error

```
Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4

GThread-ERROR **: GThread system may only be initialized once.
aborting...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please tell how to fix this issue

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of JavaFX are you using? Please, note FX2.x is not supported on RedHat/OEL. But FX8 is, you may want to try dev releases of FX8: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Regarding FX8:

`Prism-ES2 Error : GL_VERSION (major.minor) = 1.4` message is not an error but notification message. It will be removed in jdk8 release: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29273

`GThread-ERROR` from samples is another story. It's an issue which may be not yet fixed. See https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32436 and https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28580#comment-358413

Comment: I am using javafx2.2 in oracle linux platform

Comment: The Bug is scheduled to be fixed in Java 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088421